# Want to create a login page like facebook login, but have no idea where to start

Tags: java, android, facebook

I'm in the process of making an alternative facebook app for android, but I have no idea where to start. I'm looking at the Facebook SDK but that seems like it's used for people who want to use Facebook as their platform for their own seperate apps. I want to make a login screen like facebook login screen, and I'm looking at their SDK but their SDK seems like it's for completely different apps that use facebook as their platform. I'm just really dumbstruck about how I would do this facebook alternative. I'm pretty new to programming aswell. However, making something like a facebook app alternative, where would I start?

Comment: making something like a facebook app alternative, where would I start?

Comment: this is the project I want to make, i understand it'll be extremely difficult (especially at my level of knowledge) but still i'm devoted to this but I'm just kinda stuck on where to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, the Facebook SDK fits your need flawlessly.

users will have to grant you the privileges to read & write on their behalf and then, the SDK is the limit.

i suggest you take a look at the Getting Started guide & search 4 a good library.

Comment: really? thanks, I was getting so confused because all the examples were for apps that wanted to use facebook as their platform, not an app for facebook itself. i really appreciate this man, thanks.